# get JSON value from a JSON Structure definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

(Using JQuery & JavaScript)

I've this JSON structure:

```
var jCRUD = {
  DataTable: [
    { title: "Data", data: function(d) {return _.toDate(d.registre.Data, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:nn");} }
    , { title: "Fil", data: 'registre.Fil' }
    , { title: "Usuari", data: 'registre.Usuari' }
  ]
};
```

The "data" element contains a reference of a sub-json structure to retrieve data from a return of an AJAX call.
I mean: From a REST service I obtain a resultset as a JSON like this:

```
var returnedAJAX = {registres: [
  registre: {
    Data: '2016-01-15'
    , Fil: 'Nom del fil'
    , Usuari: 'Seak'
  }
]};
```

I want to get the value specified in the first JSON, something like this:

```
value1 = returnedAJAX.registres[0]. <------ jCRUD.Datatable[0].data (it's a function, then i must execute it to obtain the return value '15-01-2016')
value2 = returnedAJAX.registres[0]. <------ jCRUD.Datatable[1].data (it's 'registre.Fil', then i must obtain the value 'Nom del fil')
value3 = returnedAJAX.registres[0]. <------ jCRUD.Datatable[2].data (it's 'registre.Usuari', then i must obtain the value 'Seak')
```

Is similar as a Mustache template, that i can specify a partial JSON content or a function.

I'm sorry if i did'nt explained well.

Comment: What you are doing with function in json won't work without using `eval()` which is not safe. Why do you need function in the json in the first place?

Comment: Because i need to format the date to a Spanish notation. Basicly I want to be flexible as Moustache does (and JSON philosophy says)

Comment: Use other properties of your data to signify things like that. Then read those properties and react accordingly. The idea of putting functions in the json is not a good one

Comment: Ok, I understand. But the objective of my question is not the function. I don't know how to obtain the value2 and value3.

Comment: Edited the question because of detected a mistake in last example

Comment: I'm not clear at all what you are asking. First it is important to note that JSON is a string data format and is not the same as a javascript object or rray literal. If you are dealing with objects and not JSON strings the issues are very different regarding functions and other object references

Comment: I've in a string a suffix ('registre.Fil') and i want to know how to construct something like: returnedAJAX.registres[0].registre.Fil dinamically

Comment: Can you use multiple properties instead of one with a dot in it? Then you can do something like `registres[0][propertyOne][propertyTwo]`

Comment: Yes, I could, but I want to do something like s datatable definition, being able to specify on Columns properties a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution with eval() (didn't know the existence of it):

```
value2 = eval('returnedAJAX.registres[0].'+ jCRUD.Datatable[1].data);
value3 = eval('returnedAJAX.registres[0].'+ jCRUD.Datatable[2].data);
```

I must test it further, but I think I'm in the way.